# Conditional generic binding in Ninject based on type constraint

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I need to perform a generic `binding` on `Ninject` but I'm having some issues. These are the classes:

```cs
public class BaseBL<TEntity> : IDisposable, IBaseBL<TEntity> 
        where TEntity : class
{
     ....
}
```

```cs
public class BaseLogAuditoriaBL<TEntity> : BaseBL<TEntity>, IBaseBL<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : BaseLogAuditoriaEntity
{
  ....
}
```

I want that when my `TEntity` inherit from `BaseLogAuditoriaEntity` it calls the `BaseLogAuditoriaBL`, else it calls the `BaseBL`

In this case, how could I configure my `bindings` in a generic way for that?

It works if I put it in each class, but I need a generic solution for this issue.

Example:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseBL<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<Loja>)).To(typeof(BaseLogAuditoriaBL<>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `When(..)` syntax to create a conditional binding which fullfills your needs:

```
public static class BaseBLBindingExtensions
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object> WhenEntityMatchesType<TEntityType>(
        this IBindingWhenSyntax<object> syntax)
    {
        return syntax.When(request => DoesEntityMatchType(request, typeof(TEntityType)));
    }

    private static bool DoesEntityMatchType(IRequest request, Type typeToMatch)
    {
        return typeToMatch.IsAssignableFrom(request.Service.GenericTypeArguments.Single());
    }
}
```

Which is then used like:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseBL<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseLogAuditoriaBL<>))
    .WhenEntityMatchesType<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>();
```

Full example including unit tests (using XUnit and FluentAssertions):

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Activation;
using Ninject.Syntax;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace NinjectTest.SO40310046
{
    public interface IBaseBL<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    { }

    public class BaseBL<TEntity> : IBaseBL<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    { }

    public class SimpleEntity { }

    public class BaseLogAuditoriaEntity
    { }

    public class ChildBaseLogAuditorialEntity: BaseLogAuditoriaEntity
    { }

    public class BaseLogAuditoriaBL<TEntity> : BaseBL<TEntity>, IBaseBL<TEntity>
        where TEntity: BaseLogAuditoriaEntity
    { }

    public static class BaseBLBindingExtensions
    {
        public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object> WhenEntityMatchesType<TEntityType>(this IBindingWhenSyntax<object> syntax)
        {
            return syntax.When(request => DoesEntityMatchType(request, typeof(TEntityType)));
        }

        private static bool DoesEntityMatchType(IRequest request, Type typeToMatch)
        {
            return typeToMatch.IsAssignableFrom(request.Service.GenericTypeArguments.Single());
        }
    }

    public class UnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseBL<>));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseLogAuditoriaBL<>))
                .WhenEntityMatchesType<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>();


            kernel.Get<IBaseBL<SimpleEntity>>()
                .Should().BeOfType<BaseBL<SimpleEntity>>();

            kernel.Get<IBaseBL<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>>()
                .Should().BeOfType<BaseLogAuditoriaBL<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>>();

            kernel.Get<IBaseBL<ChildBaseLogAuditorialEntity>>()
                .Should().BeOfType<BaseLogAuditoriaBL<ChildBaseLogAuditorialEntity>>();
        }
    }
}
```

### Alternative

Considering that your `BaseLogAuditoriaBL` already defines the type constraint it might be a viable alternative to use a convention based binding (created for example using [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) which scans for types which inherit from `BaseBL`, checks for type constraints, and then scans for all types adhering to constraint and then creates specific, non-conditional, bindings for these.
The resulting bindings should be something like:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<>)).To(typeof(BaseBL<>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>))
    .To(typeof(BaseLogAuditoriaBL<BaseLogAuditoriaEntity>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseBL<ChildBaseLogAuditoriaEntity>))
    .To(typeof(BaseLogAuditoriaBL<ChildBaseLogAuditoriaEntity>));
```

Pro:

- Resolution is faster than when using `When(...)` constraints

Con:

- Only works when assemblies containing entities are known at startup time - when conventions are applied
- Increases startup time